# showNotification in react-admin doesn't work, Still

Tags: react-admin

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-6nzp0
please see /src/posts/postEdit.js line 73.
no notification show.

Could you add a working code on the sandbox?

though there are other discussion:
[showNotification in react-admin doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062100/shownotification-in-react-admin-doesnt-work)
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3402
they all did not work.

I need a working code on the sandbox so I know what I miss.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`showNotification` is a redux action creator. It creates the action object but does not dispatch it.

You have to `connect` the component which needs to show a notification and use the connected dispatcher.

Here, I suggest you extract the button in a separate component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { showNotification } from 'react-admin';

const MyButton = connect(undefined, { showNotification })(props => (
    <button
        onClick={() => {
            props.showNotification("xxx");
            // return false;
        }}
    >
        Click -----
    </button>
))
```

Then use this button in your Edit component

Comment: it works now, thanks. I have update the sandbox. but the type seems not working. and where should i found the these rules in the official document?

Comment: Thank you, it works! I set `props:any` in TypeScript to satisfy the compiler. There is surely a more elegant way, but this makes it pass the tests for now.